# WCF service: Can't call methods through the 'WebHttpBinding' endpoint

Tags: wcf

I've created WCF service, here is it's configuration section:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service name="McActivationApp.EnrollmentService" behaviorConfiguration="McActivationApp.EnrollmentServicBehavior">
    <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="McActivationApp.IEnrollmentService"/>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="McActivationApp.IEnrollmentService" />
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="McActivationApp.EnrollmentServicBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
```

I connected to the service with WcfTestClient, added service and can call only methods that are in "IEnrollmentService (MetadataExchangeHttpBinding_IEnrollmentService)" section (they work as expected).

But methods from another section "IEnrollmentService (WebHttpBinding_IEnrollmentService)" are not callable. When I try to call any of them I receives the following error:

> Failed to invoke the service. Possible
>   causes: The service is offline or
>   inaccessible; the client-side
>   configuration does not match the
>   proxy; the existing proxy is invalid.
>   Refer to the stack trace for more
>   detail. You can try to recover by
>   starting a new proxy, restoring to
>   default configuration, or refreshing
>   the service.

Error Details:

```
The Address property on ChannelFactory.Endpoint was null.  The ChannelFactory's Endpoint must have a valid Address specified.
   at System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory.CreateEndpointAddress(ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
   at System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory`1.CreateChannel()
   at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.CreateChannel()
   at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.CreateChannelInternal()
   at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.get_Channel()
   at EnrollmentServiceClient.UpdateEnrollmentProfile(String enrollmentId, String siteName, String deployServerName, Int32 methodId, String deviceClass, String deviceName, String registrationCode)
```

**Question 1:**
Am I correctly understand that for case of "IEnrollmentService (WebHttpBinding_IEnrollmentService)" methods calling I need to specify additionally some endpoint?

**Question 2:**
Can I get workable that at all?

**Question 3:**
Should I care about them (as I will be able to call methods from my 'custom' application)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you, guys, for your answers, they gave me some food to think. Here are answers on my questions:

**Answer1:**

Actually, as is stated by "marc_s" the problem is that my service was configured as 'REST' service, so answer is "Yes" to get those services accessible for WcfTestClient application additional endpoint (basicHttpBinding) is required.

**Answer2:**

As is stated in "answer1": yes, to get it workable you need to add basicHttpBinding endpoint.

**Answer3:**

It depends. If you don't plan to do 'testing' with WcfTestClient - don't care. In my particular case I will implement unit tests to check method call results, so workability in WcfTestClient  not important.

Thanks you and "+1" for each helpful answer.

P.S. The reason why I've accepted own answer is that is consistent with questions (that are essential for me).

Answer (score 2):

WCFTestClient does not support REST services (WebHttpBinding).

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to call methods on a service with `webHttpBinding` (REST) using a regular browser - no WcfTestClient needed.... that's the whole point (and benefit) of REST - it's just a "XML-over-HTTP" service (vastly simplified).

Just simply point your browser at your service endpoint

```
http://YourServer/YourVirtualDirectory/YourService.svc
```

and you should be able to see your service living there...

Comment: Yes, I see that service. But I don't see its methods. Or they are not displayed in way as WebServices do? I just need to 'use' them and that's it. Right?

Comment: In .NET 4 / WCF 4, you should be able to configure an automatic help page being generated from the service methods (no such feature in WCF 3.5, unfortunately)