# WCF: Can't call own WCF service

Tags: .net, wcf, wcfserviceclient

I have my WCF service, I've created reference to it from MSTest project. Here is example how I am calling service methods:

```
IEnrollmentService serviceClient = ChannelFactory<IEnrollmentService>
    .CreateChannel(new BasicHttpBinding(),
                   new EndpointAddress("http://localhost/EnrollmentService.svc"));

PublishResult res = serviceClient.PublishEnrollmentProfile(...);
```

Instead of execution I've got the following error:

> The content type application/xml;
>   charset=utf-8 of the response message
>   does not match the content type of the
>   binding (text/xml; charset=utf-8). If
>   using a custom encoder, be sure that
>   the IsContentTypeSupported method is
>   implemented properly. The first 710
>   bytes of the response were: '`Sendera:ActionNotSupported`The message with
>   Action '' cannot be processed at the
>   receiver, due to a ContractFilter
>   mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher.
>   This may be because of either a
>   contract mismatch (mismatched Actions
>   between sender and receiver) or a
>   binding/security mismatch between the
>   sender and the receiver.  Check that
>   sender and receiver have the same
>   contract and the same binding
>   (including security requirements, e.g.
>   Message, Transport,
>   None).'. ---> 
>   System.Net.WebException: The remote
>   server returned an error: (500)
>   Internal Server Error..

As far as I understood, there are some issues between ContractFilter and EndpointDispatcher. I've tried to goodgle, but found nothing understandable...

I've also tried to call wcf service methods in another way:

```
EnrollmentServiceClient serviceClient = new EnrollmentServiceClient("http://localhost/EnrollmentService.svc");

PublishResult res = serviceClient.PublishEnrollmentProfile(...);
```

That returns me another error:

> Could not find endpoint element with
>   name
>   'http://localhost/McActivation/EnrollmentService.svc'
>   and contract
>   'EnrollmentServiceReference.IEnrollmentService'
>   in the ServiceModel client
>   configuration section. This might be
>   because no configuration file was
>   found for your application, or because
>   no endpoint element matching this name
>   could be found in the client element..

**Question1:**

What is a correct way to instantiate wcf service client?

**Questions2:**

What is wrong in my case?

Thanks a lot.

P.S. With some issues I can connect to service with WcfTestClient, more details are here:
[WCF service: Can't call methods through the 'WebHttpBinding' endpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4648922/wcf-service-cant-call-methods-through-the-webhttpbinding-endpoint)

P.P.S. Here is server side WCF service configuration:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service name="McActivationApp.EnrollmentService" behaviorConfiguration="McActivationApp.EnrollmentServicBehavior">
    <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="McActivationApp.IEnrollmentService"/>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="McActivationApp.IEnrollmentService" />
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="McActivationApp.EnrollmentServicBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: Hard to say without knowing your service configuration.

Comment: Can you connect with the wcf test client? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552364.aspx

Comment: In situations like this I like to start with a working example and reverse engineer my application until it starts working.  Here's a sample app from MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd936243.aspx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your problem is this: your **service config** defines a `webHttpBinding` endpoints - that's a **REST** ("Xml-over-HTTP") endpoint....

Yet, your client uses a `basicHttpBinding` and this is a **SOAP** binding - those are **not** compatible!

You need to change this to make sure the service endpoint(s) offered by the service side are such that the client can connect to it.

So:

- either add another endpoint to your service config with the `basicHttpBinding` and connect to that endpoint

or:

- change your client side to use `webHttpBinding`

Comment: I did that for basicHttpBinding on both sides... Thanks a lot! But if server is configured to use 'webHttpBinding' and I switch client to use 'webHttpBinding' I still receives 'The message with Action '' cannot be processed at the receiver, due to a ContractFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher...' error message.

Comment: Also, the 1st way to instantiate service is a correct, the 2nd still doesn't work

Comment: @Budda: if you switch the client to webHttpBinding, you're also changing from SOAP to REST, and this means: completely recreate your client side proxy. Those two standards are **totally** different and just simply changing the client-side config won't be enough.....

Comment: @Budda: the second way you're trying to create your client-side proxy expects to get the **name** of an endpoint config section in your config file (`<endpoint name="XYZ">`) - not the URL as you're supplying... there's no constructor to take in just a service URL.

Comment: Yes, 2nd way (when end point name is used as constructor parameter) also works... Earlier it showed that something is wrong with URI... Thanks a lot!